# How to stop a '\n' or '\t' from working in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to open a new file like this:

```
new_path = '/Users\KamilaLipman\Documents\Coding\PyCharm\venv\Learning_Python\Learning~Input+Output\the_week.txt'
more_days = open(new_path, 'w')
```

But the \n, \v and \t gets interpreted as escape codes.
Because of this I get an error saying that the file does not exist:

```
C:\Users\KamilaLipman\Documents\Coding\PyCharm\venv\Scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/KamilaLipman/Documents/Coding/PyCharm/PythonLearning.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How could I fix this without changing my file names?

Could I use a forward slash(/)?

(I am new to Python so sorry if this is a very easy problem)

Comment: You're better off using raw strings, as Garrett Gutierrez's answer suggests. But yes, you could use forward slashes in place of backslashes, and it would work. In almost all of WIndows (but not a few weird edge cases), you can use forward slashes, and that includes all the bits of Windows that Python needs for the `open` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `r` before the string to specify it is a raw string.

```
new_path = r'/Users\KamilaLipman\Documents\Coding\PyCharm\venv\Learning_Python\Learning~Input+Output\the_week.txt'
```